# Update Access Database Linked to SharePoint Using CSV File

Tags: database, ms-access, csv, sharepoint

**Synopsis**

I am needing to bridge a gap between a CSV file and an Access 2007 database linked to a SharePoint list. The end goal is to fully automate this process: Remedy > CSV > Access > SharePoint

**Problem Details**

*Remedy ---> CSV*
I am using a [macro in BMC Remedy](http://service-it-remedy.web.cern.ch/service-it-remedy/clients/aruser/Macros3.html) to run a report and export data to a CSV file. Each time the macro runs, it is set up to overwrite the previous version of the CSV file.

*CSV --x Access*
While I can [import the CSV table](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-a-text-file-d6973101-9547-4315-a8f8-02911b549306) (as a text file) to Access, the program won't let me update the database. Creating macros, relationships or queries is impossible since the CSV file is overwritten each time the Remedy macro runs. When I attempt to copy the CSV table to the linked database (using export feature in Access) I get the following error:

> You can't delete the table '*tablename*'; it is participating in one or more relationships.

*Access --> SharePoint*
The Access database I am wanting to update is linked to a SharePoint list so that any edits made (and saved) in Access update SharePoint.

**Work-Around**

I can copy & paste the data from the CSV to the Access database, but am wanting a better solution that doesn't require any maintenance.

I have tried creating a macro, but when I use RunCommand > SelectAll I get the following error:

> The command or action 'SelectAll' isn't available now.

Is it possible to do this with a macro or do I need a VB script?

Comment: Have you considered migrating from Access to SQL server ? You'd have a lot more options from there.

Comment: I'm using Access because of the link to SharePoint (which works great). It's the updating part that is only working manually. The process needs to be automated.